# facebook oauth dialog prompted infinite times

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to login using facebook credentials into my app.
If my device has the facebook app installed, then after authentication,the dialog box " would ike to access your public profile, friend list " keeps popping up infinite times inspite of hitting the ok button.
But the same scenario works fine when facebook app is not installed in my device.

Can you point where i am going wrong?

**Edit (Code included)**

```
void signInWithFaceBook{
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {              
            if (session.isOpened()) {                                       
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                //my code
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {        
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);        
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

The signInWithFaceBook() is called when i click a login-with-facebook button.
Also I noticed that onActivityResult() receives resultcode always as 0 when i test with my facebook app installed.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @MingLi Thank u for the response. Please look through the code.

Comment: are you calling signInWithFaceBook from anywhere else? Is this in a fragment or activity? From the code that you currently have posted, I don't see anything immediate issues.

Comment: I am not calling signInWithFaceBook it from anywhere else. Also this is in an activity.

Comment: **Solved the issue.** The problem was that I had updated my package and class name. But I failed to update the same on my facebook app settings. Hence the trouble